# Nodejs request function still not finished but code proceeds to the next step?

Tags: node.js, callback, request

kinda new with nodejs and I can't seem to make my callback function work. Now my function just wants to check if URL exists

```
const request = require('request')
const URL = 'http://sampleurl.com'
var urlexists = false

async _urlExists(URL){
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2'){
        urlexists = true
      } else {
        throw new Error(`url is not working: ${URL}`)
      }
    })
  }
```

problem is, my code proceeds to the next, meaning *result is passed*, but after a couple of seconds, console shows the throwing of error saying *url is not working: ${URL}*.

Basically i just call
`await this._urlExists(URL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_urlExists` function is returning immediately after calling `request`, before waiting for a response. The `_urlExists` function needs to return a Promise in order for the caller to know when the data is ready.

I looked up the `request` npm package that you're using and it doesn't support Promises without using the `request-promise-native` wrapper package.

However, you can still wrap the `request` call in a Promise:

```
async _urlExists(URL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode.toString()[0] === '2'){
                urlexists = true;
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                reject(`url is not working: ${URL}`);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, when you call `await this._urlExists`, the function will pause to wait for the `resolve` or `reject` response before proceeding. To catch the error from a possible `reject` call, wrap the `_urlExists` call in a `try-catch` block.

Also make sure that the function you're calling `await this._urlExists` is declared as `async`, because the `await` keyword can only be used inside functions that are `async`.

If you encounter any problems or questions while implementing my solution, please let me know in a comment.

Comment: How about `const request = require('request-promise')`

Comment: Tested the sample code and is working! Thank you alot!

Comment: @Octane that package uses Bluebird promises which I am not experienced in and is not necessary for your usecase, so I recommend using [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native), which uses native Javascript Promises.

Comment: @Octane No problem! Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped you